# Cleaning Masterclave

Tags: microbiology

When i finish operation. My masterclave has smell, I think has media moulecular bind into the surface and microbial can live in. My labs don't have SOP to clean it. I promote use detergent but wonder it'll bad effect in the suface. Do you know how I can clean masterclave effective?
[image]

This's my masterclave

Comment: Have you contacted the manufacturer?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I don't think it. I will contact manufacturer.